# Where can one find the rich list of the top 100 EOS account holders?

Tags: rich-list

Does EOS have a rich list to show the top account holders of EOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EOS Flare has a page where accounts are ordered descendingly by the amount of EOS they hold:

https://eosflare.io/whales